# Render html to page from database PHP

Tags: php, html

i have a table which have records of html code, how can i render the html code to the page using PHP when i fetch them it show me as string watch in picture

[image: Example of code]

example of html is

```
<pre class="prettyprint linenums"><code>else { echo '<form = "nav-login" method="post" onsubmit="return noEmptyUserFields();" action="includes/login.inc.php"> <input type="text" id="uidz" name="uid" placeholder="Username/e-mail"> <input type="password" id="pwdz" name="pwd" placeholder="password"> <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button> </form> <a href="signup.php">Sign up</a>'; } </code></pre> <p><strong>But it responds to my javascript which is outside of the php which looks like this:</strong></p> <pre class="prettyprint linenums"><code><form class="signup-form" method="post" onsubmit="return noEmptyUserFields();" action="includes/signup.inc.php"> <input type="text" id="first" name="first" placeholder="Firstname"> <input type="text" id="last" name="last" placeholder="Lastname" > <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" > <input type="text" id="uid" name="uid" placeholder="Username" > <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" ></p2> <button type="submit" name="submit">Sign up</button></form> </code></pre>
```

in short it behaves like string but i want to show the html on page

Comment: It depends upon how do you fetch the content from Db and how you have coded to show it. Can you show that code to me?

Comment: i stored the html in database like string and fetching normally from databse in laravel using Question::all();

and want to show the html of the database on page

Comment: Can you post the code of the laravel function in your question so that we can understand how you are passing the HTML content?

Comment: i took the Snapshots but theres no any option for me to upload images in reply how should i show you

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Post text. Edit the question. Use the code formatting features available.

Comment: problem was solved, so thanks both of you